# Android: Saving image on Android Phone from ImageView in a Fragment

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, save, fragment

So I have this fragment here that looks like:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is save the image on my phone (in the file downloads or gallery or ... ).

I have scanned Stackoverflow and the internet but my code is not working. I do not get an error, but I also don't get a picture stored on my phone. What could be my problem? The code I used comes from Stackoverflow.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    Button download;
    ImageView DownloadImage;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        DownloadImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageToDownload);
        download = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonDownloadImage);


        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.200.2/android_login_api/images/actie.png").into(DownloadImage);

        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               saveImageLocally(DownloadImage);

            }
        });
        return v;
    }


    private String saveImageLocally(ImageView iv) {
        iv.buildDrawingCache();

        Bitmap bmp = iv.getDrawingCache();

        File storageLoc = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS); //context.getExternalFilesDir(null);

        File file = new File(storageLoc, "test" + ".jpg");

        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();

            scanFile(getActivity(), Uri.fromFile(file));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "true";
    }

    private static void scanFile(Context context, Uri imageUri){
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        scanIntent.setData(imageUri);
        context.sendBroadcast(scanIntent);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this permissions in `Manifest.xml`, because i tried your code and logged its working perfect :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Actually i tried your code and logged , the result : `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Try to look logcats like :

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("bitmap","not found , "+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("bitmap","io ex , "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what  a stupid mistake of me to forget those permitions. thanks!

Comment: @KahnKah no problem. I will suggest you to trace exceptions and log them when creating/handling files . Maybe you will get more issues . If you get one issue in your logcat its easy to find solution.